# REST API Update Product HTTP Method PUT or POST?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

The REST API documentation says that `PUT /V1/products/{sku}` creates rather than updates.

Is that an error in the docs because I would have assumed that it is an update method and **POST** being the method to create?

Answer (score 5):

POST and PUT route to same method save, but with POST you cannot pass `sku`

```
  <route url="/V1/products" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/products/:sku" method="PUT">
        <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="save" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

Comment: Ok that's understandable but why would the docs say that the PUT also creates a product? I mean the sku in the path always is for identifying a product isn't it? Or can one actually create product using PUT /V1/products/:sku also?

Comment: You should use Post for create and Put for update operation.
Documentation is autogenerated from dockblock, this is why put and post have same description

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this page: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html#RESTAPI-Resource-Products-HTTPMethod-PUT-products--id

I can see for PUT:

> Description: Allows you to update an existing product.

Comment: It's docs for magento 1.x

Comment: Sorry I should have written in the text that this was regarding Magento 2, that page is about v1.

Comment: And sorry for not reading that KAndy had already pointed this out :-) I am a complete beginner when it comes to stackexchange

Comment: Well regardless of the major magento version, the rest API has the same version, doesn't it? So there is some use in pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar problem but in my, case PUT does not work properly because:

1) FInd all products of the cart:

`GET: http://my_host.dev/index.php/rest/V1/carts/8/items`

( I don't know yet how to find client **cartId**) I found correct number by increasing the number from 1.

2) the answer was:

```
[ { "item_id": 11, "sku": "MH07-M-Green", "qty": 1, "name": "Hero Hoodie", "price": 54, "product_type": "configurable", "quote_id": "8", "product_option":{ "extension_attributes":{ "configurable_item_options":[{"option_id": "90", "option_value": 53 }, {"option_id": "138",…] } } } ]
```

2) Update cart item price by:

```
{ "cartItem": { "itemId": 11, "sku": "MH07-M-Green", "qty": 2, "name": "Hero Hoodie", "price": 1000, "productType": "configurable ", "quoteId": "8" } }
```

3) I get not Updated item price in cart (My response is the same as in point 1). I have to say also that I can delete Items from cart. 
Any solution for this?

Thank you